# Applescript fails with Big Sur - permissions issue?

Tags: finder, applescript, permission

I have VMWare and Parallels and I've learned that if you don't exclude them from Time Machine they wind up bloating the backups. As a compromise, I set up a cron job to make a once-daily copy that is not excluded from TM. Because you can't just use "cp -r" to do this, I use AppleScript to instruct the finder to do it:

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate folder "Parallels" of home to folder "Parallels backup" of home with replacing
end tell
```

This used to work, but under Big Sur it no longer does - I get a message that the Finder has gotten an AppleScript timeout. My guess is that I have to grant something Full Disk Access in the Privacy tab of Security, but I don't know what. I tried granting it to osascript, but it didn't help.

Comment: 1. `cron` is deprecated in **macOS** as `launchd` is the **macOS** way to do things that `cron` used to be used for.  (You can still use it but `launchd` is really the way to go!) 2. In this use case, **AppleScript** and especially **Finder** is the worst way to do this considering the possible sizes of the **virtual machines**.  I'd use `launchd` and a _shell script_ to accomplish the task. You simple first delete the **Parallels** _directory_ from within the **Parallels Backup** _directory_, then copy the **Parallels** _directory_ to the **Parallels Backup** _directory_.

Comment: I highly recommend you read the _manual pages_ for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`. Then create a **Launch Agent** to run your _shell script_. You can read the _manual page_ for _`command`_ in **Terminal** by typing _`man command`_, then press **enter**, or **for easier reading**, just type _`command`_ and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Comment: You can't use cp to copy these things. And the issue in the question isn't whether cron works or not (it does), but rather why the script seemingly lacks permission to act. When this worked, a progress dialog would pop up while the copy happened and there was never a timeout. Now, the dialog doesn't show up.

Comment: RE: "You can't use cp to copy these things." --  Sure you can, I do it all the time! Also, I would not suggest something that I haven't already done myself, or know for a fact that is can be done.

Comment: [This blog post on launchd scheduling](https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/launchd-plist-examples-startinterval-startcalendarinterval/) may come in handy. Possibly the syntax has changed a bit (launchd development seems to be a bit like that) but at least it will get you in the right direction. If you choose the right user (possibly yourself) then the permissions issue may well disappear.

Comment: Launchd isn’t the issue. Even if I use launchd I still get the applescript timeout.

Comment: And using the finder instead of cp finishes instantly because of APFS and copy-on-write.